# Kotlin ImagePicker Solution After Version Update

Tags: android, kotlin, imagepicker

I used in my project this ImagePicker Library.

https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker

I used it this way in the old version, but this "getFile" function has been removed in the new version. I have to use the new version because of the "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission error in Android 13.

.getFile removed in v2.0

https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker/pull/200/files#diff-a18addafe8b8ac956554293f48d74cf38a8b260efcef49b8c25a6b3965d11038

Code :

```
private fun addPhoto() {
       requireActivity().showImagePicker {
           if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && it.data != null) {
               val result = it.data.data
               if (result != null) {
                   val imageFile: File = ImagePicker.getFile(it.data)!!
                   listPhotos = ArrayList()
                   listPhotos.add(imageFile)
                   savePhoto()
               }
           } else if (it.resultCode == ImagePicker.RESULT_ERROR) {
               toastError(ImagePicker.getError(it.data))
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: There is no requirement for this library to be limited to files that your app can access on the filesystem. That's why the library eliminated `getFile()`, as I understand it, as it cannot be supported. Use the `Uri` that you get back: pass it to your image-loading library, etc.

Comment: So what should I write instead of getfile?

Comment: `it.data.data` is your `Uri`. Use that.

Comment: I changed to 

val imageFile: File = it.data.data

Comment: But gives error :

Type mismatch.
Required:
File
Found:
Uri?

Comment: Could you describe what is the goal here?
How you are using the file with the old implementation?

Comment: In the old version, I use it as in the code block above. @vasberc

Comment: The error is because the data you get is Uri but you try to assign it to a File object, there is an extension fun that converts a Uri to File.

The only you have to do is to call it.data.data.toFile().

This extension is in the androidx.core:core-ktx library.

Does this solve your issue?